# Error bars in log space, using 'symlog'

Tags: logging, format, space

So, I am attempting to plot a set of values and their respective error bars in python, in log space. My code looks like this:

```
from pylab import *
import csv
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig1=plt.figure()
ax=fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.errorbar(xvalues, yvalues, yerr=[yerr1,yerr2],xerr=[xerr1,xerr2], fmt='ro')
plt.show()
```

where 'xvalues' and 'yvalues' are the two datasets that I want to plot, and yerr1, yerr2, xerr1, and xerr2 are the positive and negative errors associated with their respective datasets *in linear space*.

The problem is this: when I run this segment of the code, I end up with a plot whose error bars are inconsistent with expected values. Further, the majority of said 'errors' have negative values. This may or may not be of importance, but anyway...

Any feedback or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Niharika